# Does using the iterator member function "empty()" only work on certain vector types?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm getting an error when I use the iterator member function "empty()" on vector of type int, but not vector of type string (using the correct terms to the best of my understanding).

vector of type int:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    vector<int> ivec = {0,1,2};
    auto iter = ivec.begin();
    if(!iter->empty())
        cout << "not empty" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
error C2839: invalid return type 'int *' for overload 'operator ->'
error C2039: 'empty': is not a member of 'std::Vector_iterator....'
```

vector of type string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    vector<string> svec = {"text"};
    auto iter = svec.begin();
    if(!iter->empty())
        cout << "not empty" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
not empty
```

## Update

- I now understand that depending on the type that is in the vector can you only perform certain operations.
- You are not performing the operations on the iterator itself (because it is a pointer to the element in the container), but on the object that the iterator points to.

Comment: You are asking whether `int` is different to `string`. Yes.

Comment: Table 3.6. C++ Primer, by Stanley B. Lippman, Josée LaJoie,
Barbara E. Moo:
Standard Container Iterator Operations:
*iter,
iter->, 
etc.
What is going on here? Please explain?

Comment: We don't have your book.  Update this question or post another with enough context to be a complete self-contained question. See [mcve]

Comment: @John Does that table list `empty()` as a standard container iterator operation?

Comment: @juanchopanza it does not. But I thought that it implied so. I understand what's going on now.

Comment: What question do you want to have answered from the call of empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`empty()` is not "an iterator member function". You are not calling `empty()` on the iterator - you are dereferencing the iterator, and calling `empty()` on the vector element that the iterator refers to. It might be clearer if you replace `iter->empty()` with an equivalent form `(*iter).empty()`

In still other words,

```
auto iter = vec.begin();
iter->empty();
```

is equivalent to

```
vec[0].empty();
```

Here, iterators are not involved at all; hopefully, this would make the point extra clear.

Now, it so happens that `std::string` does have a member function `empty()`, while `int` of course does not (seeing as it's not a class type and so can't have any member functions). That's why your code compiles with `vector<string>` but not `vector<int>`.